# What git commits are responsible for a difference?

Tags: git

Given the output of **git diff origin/firefly origin/master -- src/crush**, how can I find the commits that are responsible for them ?

Something like:

```
$ git blame-diff origin/firefly origin/master -- src/crush
58ea017 crush: CrushTester: add test_with_crushtool()
e10417d CrushTreeDumper.h: prefer ++operator for non-primitive iterator
```

The use case is when a subdirectory ( **src/crush** above ) is backported from **master** to the stable branch **firefly**. Instead of cherry-picking the relevant commits, we exclude the ones that should not be backported and cherry-pick the others. In other words : we keep the **src/crush** directory in sync except for a few selected commits.

The person who did the backporting knows which commits were not cherry picked but ... he forgot to list them. The reviewer of the backport has dozens of cherry picked commits to merge into the **firefly** stable branch, including some conflict resolutions. Because of the conflicts he can't use **git cherry** to sort out which commit have been excluded.

The diff output is small compared to the aggregated size of the commits to review. If the reviewer could figure out which commits in **master** introduced the hunks, it would be easier to check that all hunks indeed belong to a series of patch that must not be backported. It would help find if a hunk was accidentally backported although it should not have. Or if a hunk that should have been backported is missing.

The backported could **git log -L linestart,lineend:src/crush/CrushWrapper.h** using linestart and lineend from a diff hunk. He could then apply the commit, diff again and see that a number of hunks reduced. And repeat the process until there is no diff. The list of commits applied to reach that point are the one the original backporter excluded from the cherry-pick.

This semi manual method is however difficult and it is likely that the backporter will go faster by carefully analyzing each and every line of the diff, even if it is a few thousand lines long. Would there be a way to script this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
 git log -- <file>
```

in your case

```
 git log -- src/crush
```

Comment: You can also use the `-p` (`--patch`) option to display the corresponding diffs.

Comment: this will show logs that are not related to the diff described above